# Physical Meaning of Time Dependent Portion of a Quantum Stationary State

Tags: quantum-mechanics

What is the physical meaning of the time dependent portion of stationary states in Quantum Mechanics? As an example, consider a particle trapped within an infinite square well potential of width $L$ and centered about $x=0$. Such a particle has the standard time-dependent wavefunctions:
$$\psi_{n}(x,t) = A\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}\left(x+\frac{L}{2}\right)\right)Exp\left[iE_{n}t/\hbar\right]$$
What's strange about this equation with regards to its physical interpretation is that the term $E_n$ is completely arbitrary in the solution. Normally we assume that $V(x)=0$ everywhere within the well (from $-L/2$ to $L/2$). However, we can consider the floor of the well to be any finite value ($V(x) = V_0$). Doing so, our solution changes to the following:
$$\psi_{n}(x,t) = A\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}\left(x+\frac{L}{2}\right)\right)Exp\left[i(E_{n}+V_0)t/\hbar\right]$$
From an operator perspective this doesn't seem to change anything. After all, if we measure the potential energy, kinetic energy or any other observable quantity the time-dependent portion will come out to one due to the requirement that we take the complex conjugate of the equation when performing a measurement.

Physically this seems wrong. It doesn't seem physical that we can have a wavefunction which oscillates at an arbitrarily high frequency depending on how we define the value of the 'floor' of the quantum well. But at the same time, if we can never see the effect of this oscillation with any experimental measurement of the quantum state is it really a problem? Does the time-dependent portion even matter? Does it have any physical significance?

Thank you for taking the time to read through this question. I look forward to reading what you all think about this problem.

Comment: The time-dependent portion of a stationary state does not have physical meaning. In fact if you use the density matrix formalism instead of wave functions it isn't even there. So it's just a quirk of how we formulate QM.

Comment: Because you never measure the phase of a quantum state. You can only measure inner products, which depend on relative phases. If you make every state oscillate faster then the relative phase doesn't change.

Comment: Consider classical mechanics but from the perspective of an observer that is spinning in a circle really really quickly. Their predictions will be the same as the predictions of another observer who is standing still, but the spinning observer will say "everything seems to be spinning very quickly!" This is the kind of thing that is happening... but it turns out that we can't observe this spinning effect anyway because global phases don't change quantum states. People do use this rotating framework to help solve some other quantum problems

Comment: Just to add something here: when you are using numerical approximation methods based on the eigenfunctions of a simpler Hamiltonian, the phases actually do matter now. This is because the overlap integral enters into several parts of the interaction parts of the Hamiltonian, and thus the phases have some physical meaning in these contexts. But the time dependent oscillations of stationary states really don’t mean much. They are just a consequence of a stationary state having to do something while also conserving probability.